# Is there a way to create custom drawable shapes in android xml?

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, android-drawable

Below is an example of a rectangular border that is blue. What I want to do is create my own shape value`<shape android:shape="rectangle" >` where the shape is not rectangle, but rather just a frame with corners similar to this photo here https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180205/ecq/kisspng-video-camera-film-frame-video-camera-viewfinder-frame-for-digital-camera-5a7860497defb6.1781782515178384095158.jpg.

So far I tried playing around with the dashWidth and dashGap to try and make it fit the corners, but I've had issues. I've looked online(youtube/google) and I see shapes for lines, oval, and ring. Nothing for corner so I want to create my own

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
      <stroke
          android:width="4dp"
          android:color="#263ADD"
          android:dashWidth="80dp"
          android:dashGap="80dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android now imports SVG to XML.
Convert your image to SVG and simple import using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I could come up with is to use gradient and some attributes.
Example look like :

```
<item>
<shape>
  <gradient
      android:startColor="Your required color"
      android:centerY="Your required position"
      android:centerX="Your required position"
      android:endColor="Your required color"
      android:angle="Your required angle"
  />
</shape>
```

You can see the other's required attributes and use the position of the line .
[Attributes for Gradient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable)